# Is my friend right about omitting $c^2$ in world famous tiny equation?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, absolute-units

I know $E = mc^2$ says that inertial mass of a system is equal to the total energy content of a system in its rest frame. My friend told me the $c^2$ can be omitted from this equation because that's just an `artifact' when measuring inertia and energy in different units.

Is he right?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that answered the question, and replies to them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is basically a philosophical question, but I'm going to take what will probably be an unpopular position that your friend's reason is basically wrong in the context of an *introduction* to special relativity.

Sure, you can work in units where c = 1, and then the equation $E = m c^2$ reduces to $E = m$. But that fact alone is kind of vacuous: you can also work in units $v = 1$, where $v$ equals 1 m/s, and then $E = m c^2$ reduces to the technically equally legitimate equation $E = (9 \times 10^{16}) m$. But this clearly seems like a "less right" thing to do.

In many contexts $c$ is the *natural* velocity scale to set to 1. But that because it's a highly physically privileged speed in special relativity, and in order to understand why, you need to understand a bunch of facts like $E = m c^2$. So (I would argue that) it's subtly misrepresenting the causation to say that $E = m$ "because" $E = m c^2$ and $c = 1$. I would instead say that $c = 1$ "because" $E = m c^2$ (and several other closely related facts).

The danger of setting $c = 1$ too early when first learning special relativity is that it hides the fact that $c$ *does* have a physical value, with a unique physical significance. It's not just a convenient simplification, like doing a mechanics problem where you assume that a car is traveling at unit speed. But once you're comfortable with special relativity at an intuitive level, then yes, you can absolutely say that $E = m$ and everyone will know what you mean.

Comment: 1. Well, the non-trivial physical fact that the speed of light is invariant gives us an invariant/unambiguous way to measure space and time in the same units. Once we realize that, writing $c$ in a dimensionful manner seems like writing the distances along the north and those along the east in different units, to steal the analogy due to Wheeler. 2. The "physical value" of $c$ reflects everything about the history of the units we chose to measure lengths and time, etc., but not much about physics IMO. The only physically meaningful information is that $c$ is finite, no?

Comment: @DvijD.C. 1. Yes, I agree with you. But you do need to realize that in order to fully appreciate what it means to set $c = 1$, and to me the friend's explanation that the $c$ is just an "artifact" seems to incorrectly imply that the $c$ is as unphysical and conventional as Boltzmann's constant.

Comment: 2. Eh, I mostly agree with you, but it depends on exactly what you're assuming. I personally would say the core fact underlying special relativity is that spacetime is invariant under the Poincare group. This implies some more facts - like the fact that the speed of light is spatially isotropic and does not change over time - which may or may be implicit in the statement "the speed of light is finite", depending on your exact assumptions.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming principle of relativity, homogeneity, and isotropy (none of which are trivial, of course). However, even given all those, both Galilean and Einsteinean relativity can work. By saying "finite" I was making the distinction that nature chooses Einsteinean relativity over Galilean relativity. But yes, I agree that to even arrive at a single parameter whose value (finite or infinite) determines Galilean/Einsteinean, we need non-trivial physical assumptions, so they're baked into a notion of $c$ in the sense in which we talk about it.

Answer (score 6):

Pedagogically, I agree with `@tparker`'s answer in that I do think it is not a wise thing to rush to $c=1$ before a student is relativistically mature enough to not misunderstand it. However, ultimately, I think your friend is $100\%$ right, you can omit that $c$, and not just that, it's a bit silly to write that $c$ as an adult. ;)

---

### A Wheelerean Delight

In *Spacetime Physics*, Taylor and Wheeler discuss a nice story. I will tell a version of it which is a bit improvised (read mutilated). Imagine a town where people didn't know how to build rulers. However, there were two rail lines in the town. One went North-South and the other went East-West. The NS rail line had markings on it each meter whereas the EW rail line had markings on it each foot. So, people invented two notions of distance: an NS distance which they measured in meters, and an EW distance which they measured in feet. However, one curious kid once figured out that if you took a stick, put it along the NS rail line, measured its NS distance, and then rotated it to align it to the EW rail line, its EW length would always turn out to be $3.28$ times its NS length. So, they had this nice formula $L_{EW}=fL_{NS}$ where $f$ was a universal constant of the town, measured to be $3.28\text{ feet}/\text{meter}$. Finally, an insightful kid came along and realized that lengths of sticks remain invariant under all rotations and thus the same stick can be used to define distances along any of the directions. So, he started measuring the NS distance and the EW distance using the same unit, meter. People cried, "Oh! the dimensions won't work out!", "This is *just* a trick!", and so on. But of course, each of those sentences is wrong. The kid had discovered that the heart of the concept of distances lies in that they are rotationally invariant and this allows us (in fact, forces us) to measure distances in the same units along all directions.

### Coming Back to Question

While this is not an exact analogy, it's pretty close. In relativity, we learn that the speed of light is invariant, its value doesn't depend on the frame of reference used to measure it. This allows us to measure distances in the traditional units of time (and vice versa, i.e. it also allows us to measure times in the traditional units of length). Let's give an explicit example. Say, you know how to measure time. How do you utilize that to measure length? You can send a light signal along a direction and the time it takes for the light ray to travel a certain distance would be the value of that distance. Notice that it is incredibly important to notice that this is an unambiguous and useful way to define the unit of distance since the speed of light is invariant among all inertial frames. If you chose a sound signal to do a similar thing, you'd end up with an incredibly frame-dependent system of units where you'd always have to refer to some ground frame in which the speed of sound was supposed to be a certain value. In other words, it would not have been any actual simplification. However, with relativity, since it is ensured that the speed of light is invariant, we can measure distances in the units of time. What would this mean for, say, $\text{meters}?$ Well, since light travels $3\times10^8\text{ meters}$ in $1 \text{second}$, according to our new understanding, we can say $3\times 10^8 \text{ meters}=1 \text{second}$ because that's exactly the amount of time it takes for light to travel $3\times 10^8 \text{ meters}$ . Or, in other words, $c=1$ (notice that such a $c$ is dimensionless).

### Some Hand-Waving and General Remarks...

While rotations mix all directions of space completely into each other, Lorentz transformations of relativity don't quite mix space and time into each other to the same extent. For example, you cannot Lorentz transform a timeline vector into a spacelike vector, etc. However, there is still sufficient unification of space and time so that there is no way to escape the notion of a spacetime continuum. For example, there is no separate invariant time interval between two events and neither is there a separately invariant spatial interval between two events. You can only have an invariant spacetime interval between two events. This also motivates the use of natural units, or geometrized units, where $c=1$.

Finally, it is incredibly important to notice that the physical importance of the value of $c$ is in that it is finite (rather than infinite). If the invariant speed is infinite, then our whole scheme of measuring space in units of time breaks down (as it would break down in Galilean mechanics because the invariant speed in Galilean mechanics is, of course, infinity). So, the fact that we can set $c=1$ is not a matter of a clever way of managing equations which one could have always done. Rather, it is the most succinct form of expressing the non-trivial physical fact that there is a finite invariant speed which allows for an invariant/unambiguous unification of the units of space and time.

Generally speaking, when there is a fundamental constant of nature which relates two quantities of different units, it's a sign that we should actually measure the two quantities in the same units, making the constant dimensionless. For example, in quantum mechanics, $[x,p]=i\hbar$ allows us to set up a system where $x$ is measured in $\text{GeV}^{-1}$, $p$ is measured in $\text{GeV}$ as usual (i.e., usual after setting $c=1$!), and this makes $\hbar=1$. If you don't use natural units, $\hbar$ would have had the dimensions of action (i.e., those of angular momentum).

Comment: The railroad story is a little far-fetched, but there are real-life situations that are similar. American aviators measure altitude in feet, but horizontal distances in miles. And mariners traditionally measured horizontal distances in nautical miles and depths in fathoms.

Comment: @PM2Ring Note that even ow it is common (this is Europe, but I assume it's universal) in naval settings to use miles for distances but metres (or something else non-mily) for depth, and there is a reason (besides ranges): There is no symmetry between horizontal and vertical distnces in the sense that a ship can navigate north and west and all in between, but is confined to the surface. Thus, you cannot set a course "30 degrees in the horizontal and 7% upwards". Hence, the spatial rotation subgroup of the Poincare (or Galilean) group is, in some way, broken to $SO(2)$ in navigation.

Comment: (cont) This effectively still applies to submarines and airplanes, where the horizontal component of the motion is different from the vertical, for practical purposes.

Comment: @Toffomat Yes, but don't they need to use angles somehow? How do you define dimensionless angles above the horizontal plane if you use two different units of length?

Comment: @DvijD.C.I don't know about airplanes, I only do some sailing in my spare time. Angles above the horizon could be used for navigation (e.g. height of the sun to determine position). Practically, there defined by callling "straight up" 90° and "horizon" as 0°.

Comment: @Toffomat OK, but if you say $30^\circ$ above the horizon, and say you need to take its sine for some reason, you essentially need to convert nautical miles to fathoms or vice-versa to get that dimensionless $\sin{30^\circ}=1/2$, right?

Comment: Well, the sine of angle in degrees is well-defined as $\sum (\phi/180°\cdot\pi)^{(2n+1)}/(2n+1)!$.

Comment: @Toffomat Sure, gravity makes vertical motion rather different to horizontal motion. So it's quite reasonable to use different units for vertical distance vs horizontal distance. Of course, conversion between those units is a lot easier if you're using the metric system. OTOH, nautical miles are handy due to being related to angles on an idealized spherical Earth (and it's not that hard to adjust nautical miles to an ellipsoid model).

Comment: But then, the sun is "infinitely far" away. I guess if you, e.g., want to track the motion of an airplane form a ship, you would use the same units for height and horizontal distance. My point was just that practically, there might be good reasons to use different units for quantities that are of the same type form a fundamental physics perspective.

Comment: @user76284 I've asked a question on meta regarding this point: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12929/20427.

Comment: Can the downvoter voice the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your friend was more wrong than right, as others here have said. I am just adding some thoughts that emerged after long experience with relativity. This becomes a question of practicalities. Basically there are pros and cons to natural units (units where $c=1$ among other things).

Pros

1. reduce clutter in formulae and in long derivations
2. train one's mind to see that some things are alike to one another (e.g. space and time) or identical to one another (mass and energy, if we mean rest mass and rest energy)

Cons

1. lose a nice way to keep track of physical dimensions (I have lost track of the number of times when $c$ came to the rescue and stopped me making a simple slip in a calculation)
2. eventually when you compare theory to experiment you do have to know either the value of $c$ in your units of choice, or else the length of your apparatus in units where $c=1$. Either way you cannot avoid finding out how the speed of light in vacuum compares with the lengths and times of the equipment you are using. It is simply wrong to think one can say "$c=1$" and leave it there.

The most convenient way to apply theoretical results to experimental observations in practice depends on the type of experiment. For Earth-scale observations of distances and time, SI units are convenient. For energies and momenta in high-energy physics, use mega-electron-volts and write things like $m = 0.511\,$MeV$/c^2$ for mass and $p = 2.1\,$MeV$/c$ for momentum. But note the way $c$ here appears in the units. (Eventually the expert will drop this $c$ but they know what they are doing; do not drop it if you are not an expert.) The most convenient way in astronomy is sometimes lightyears, but you'd be surprised how often astronomers use mega-parsecs.

The Earth is 499 light-seconds from the Sun. I always thought that was a nice friendly number, and remarkably accurate.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how keeping $c$ is helpful in the dimensional analysis? The dimensions would remain consistent just as much in the formalism with $c=1$ and so I can check dimensions there just as fine, no?

Comment: @DvijD.C. Suppose we have $p_3 = p_2 - p_1$ but then we slipped up and wrote $p_3 = p_2 - E_1$. If $c=1$ then the latter might be correct. But if $c \ne 1$ then we can tell immediately that it is wrong. (I have in mind a case where particle 1 has non-zero rest mass).

Answer (score 1):

In the **Natural Units**, the speed of light in vacuum i.e. $c$ is taken to be the fundamental speed of the universe. Under this system, all the fundamental physical constants are defined in such a way that their value is just 1 (e.g. $\hbar=k_B=1$).

However, in the end one has to include the numerical values when switching from one system of units to another, say from the natural to S.I. units. This is the part of dimensional analysis. Hence, omitting in this sense is just taking $c$ to be 1 and using $E = m$ instead. You can see more [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP5G20ImveU).

Comment: All of the fundamental physical constants cannot be defined to be one. For example, the fine structure constant is a key physical constant, and it has a value of about 1/137 in all consistent systems of units .

Comment: I wanted to write -...in this system all these...- w.r.t the reduced Planck's constant and the Boltzmann constant that i put later on. Yes, I understand that not all but these three form the basis for the Natural units. Thank you pointing it out.

Comment: Ishika, isn't the invariant speed $c$ a fundamental constant *period*? Why would it be so only in natural units?

Comment: Yes, the speed of light is certainly significant, but that's true no matter what system of units you use. Natural units make equations look simpler, but as Agnius's answer mentions, they do have a pitfall. And as David said, some constants, like the fine structure constant, are dimensionless, so they aren't affected by the units you use (and of course mathematical constants like $\pi$ are also dimensionless).

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is right. If you adopt the length unit l = 299 792 458 metres then c=1 l/s. This can be convenient because in these units $E^2=m^2+p^2$ instead of $E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$.

Comment: This is not what is done. You set $299792458 \text{ meters} = 1 \text{ second}$. When we say $c=1$, we mean it--there is no units hiding with that $1$. ;)

Comment: @DvijD.C., this is precisely what I thought when I read this (I had a comment typed) and then, I looked around here and found counterexamples. I've understood the $(c=1)$ expression to mean that $c$ is the dimensionless constant $1$, not the 1 light-second per second dimensionful constant

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Yeah, as you can see, things like $E^2=m^2+p^2$ also wouldn't work out unless you make $c$ dimensionless. Maybe one can argue they'd work out "numerically" but in reality, they'd remain dimensionally inconsistent unless $c$ is truly dimensionless. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very common to "omit" constants, especially in theoretical physics.

Actually, there is a system based only on physical constants ($c,\hbar,\epsilon_0,G ...$). Physical units in this system are called *natural units* and we can "normalize" those constants by choosing a system in which their value is 1, they are called *purely natural units* (or just *natural units* again).

You can read more here: [Natural system of units in General Relativity](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~amyers/NaturalUnits.pdf) and this other [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/458851/a-question-about-natural-geometrized-units?rq=1) maybe usefull too.

Comment: Well, it's not "omitting" them, it's writing them in the most natural way.